# How do I add the default radio stations from Rhythmbox into Banshee?

Tags: rhythmbox, banshee

With the change from Rhythymbox to Banshee there are no default radio stations in 11.04. What are the default stations from 10.10 and how do I add them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default stations are:

80s

```
http://network.absoluteradio.co.uk/core/audio/ogg/live.pls?service=a8bb

http://network.absoluteradio.co.uk/core/audio/ogg/live.pls?service=a8
```

Classic Rock

```
http://network.absoluteradio.co.uk/core/audio/ogg/live.pls?service=vcbb
```

90s

```
http://network.absoluteradio.co.uk/core/audio/ogg/live.pls?service=a9bb
```

POP

```
http://network.absoluteradio.co.uk/core/audio/ogg/live.pls?service=vrbb
```

dabbl

```
http://network.absoluteradio.co.uk/core/audio/ogg/live.pls?service=albb
```

HBR1 – Dream Factory

```
http://ubuntu.hbr1.com:19800/ambient.ogg
```

Trance

```
http://ubuntu.hbr1.com:19800/trance.ogg
```

You can take any of these URLs and add them to Banshee. To do this start Banshee up and then follow the images below to add the stations you prefer.

[image]

[image]